# using weak, strong self usage in block, core data, swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, swift2, weak-references

Currently, I am doing a fetch in core data by following

```
CoreDataStack.sharedIntance.backgroundContext.performBlock({
    let fetchRequest                =   NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Schedule")
    let sortDescriptor              =   NSSortDescriptor(key: "startTime", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors    =   [sortDescriptor]
    var result  =   [Schedule]()

    mainContext.performBlockAndWait { [unowned self] in
        do {
            result = try mainContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Schedule]
            success?(result)
        } catch {
            print("error is \(error)")
        }
    }
})
```

And I am getting an error

> Reference to property mainContext in closure requires explicit self to
>   make capture semantics explicit

I notice that some of the solutions and they add `self` for the property in block.

Is it good to do that or should we create a `weak or unowned` to avoid retain cycle and what is the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: First, there are big changes in Core Data for Swift 3. Given you're not writing any production code, I'd recommend learning with that. Second, references to self requires 'self.' in all closures.

Comment: thanks.However, can you give more details about using self and will it cause leak memory ?

Comment: What is `self` here (e.g. `self.mainContext`)? Is it a UIKit object, like a View Controller?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper:Currenlty, `self` is CoreDataStack which is subclass of NSObject.

Comment: From a  Core Data perspective, I'm a bit confused about the purpose of this code snippet: if `self` is a `CoreDataStack` object, then there must be some CoreDataStack method with executes the first statement `CoreDataStack.sharedIntance.backgroundContext.performBlock(...)`. In the backgroundContext you use a var `result` which is fetched in the mainContext. Accessing `result` from the backgroundContext is invalid - it will crash.

Comment: To also clarify what `self` (implicit or explicit) is in the closures: it refers to the implicit first parameter of the enclosing method that calls `CoreDataStack.sharedIntance.backgroundContext.performBlock()`. In other words, the object bound to the method calling this first statement. Note that a _method_ has a hidden first parameter `self`, which refers to the object that calls it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you use `self` in a block, you must consider the future of that block or you can create a reference cycle and leak memory (which is why Swift requires you to be explicit). A reference cycle most often occurs when a block captures (holds a strong reference to) `self`, some other object holds onto that block, and `self` holds onto that other object. In that configuration, there is a cycle that contains both `self` and the other object, so neither can ever deallocate.

This most often happens when the block is a handler for "every time X happens, please do this." The object that holds that block and does the notification is very often owned by the thing that wants to be notified. This is probably the most common kind of reference loop. It is generally resolved by making `self` weak.

`performBlock`, however, is not this kind of function. It executes the block and then releases it. In Swift terms it is `@noescape` (and in the future it may be marked that way and you won't need to use `self.` in noescape closures). Until the block executes, `self` cannot be deallocated, but after the block executes, the cycle is immediately broken. That probably is exactly what you wanted. So using `self.` here is fine, and there's no reason to add the complexity of a weak reference.